# Header tag and paragraph tag are shown in single line tinymce

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using TinyMCE in my backend for content entry. But the content are displayed weirdly in the frontend.

I've not set any kind of css for this layout.[image]

I'm using the following tools and plugins:

```js
menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist | forecolor backcolor removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | fullscreen  preview save print | insertfile image media template link anchor codesample | ltr rtl',
  toolbar_sticky: true,
```

This is the project I'm working on.
[link](https://upscaleadventures.com/travel-style/climbing)

I couldn't find what is causing the layout issue.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

What I think you should do is use some css and make the h1 into a block(the h1 is by default block but in your case it doesn't seem to be). so that way the element after it cant be on the same line for example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        \\ this is the style you need to apply
        h1 {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--your h1 was for some reason by default displayed inline so-->
    <h1>Hello bruh!</h1>
    <p>Sup dood!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

also apply this style to the table as well. please be sure to notify me if it doesnt work.